# Is it possible to use Amazon EC2 for Android syncing to cloud backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2

I would like to provide syncing to cloud feature to an Android app.

I had read the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html & http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html

The examples being shown is using Google App Engine as backend storage.

I was wondering, is it possible not to tie to Google App Engine platform? For instance, using Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you have to do more work on hosting a web service in EC2.  Then your Android app will connect to it like [this Android example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download).  To write data instead of reading, use HTTP POST or PUT instead of GET.  You would also have to implement your own user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.  Here's the Amazon AWS SDK for Android:
http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

Yes, you will lose a little of the ease and integration of GAE, but you will gain something in flexibility.  The GAE features (e.g. user authentication) tie you into Google's Android, making it harder to support Amazon or BB Android.  And GAE limits you to their transactional HTTP model of communication.